# cant check testflight beta build on more than one device as an internal tester

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm just trying out with iOS development and so far have managed to upload my app build to app store connect and added an internal tester for internal testing. Now my problem arises when I invite an internal tester he seems to open and check the app with testflight the first time on a device, now when later he tries to test it on another device from the invite email he receives an error (screen shot attached) and cant seem to test the app. Steps I have tried so far include removing the tester and then re adding him but it don't seem to work I may be missing something very basic here but it really is very frustrating as the internal tester asks me to resend him invite as he is constantly receiving error when trying to open the app. Note re-adding the tester does indeed resends an invite but the app don't seem to load and he gets an error. Need help cause Im stuck.[image]

Comment: Once an invitation has been redeemed, it is linked to the Apple ID that was logged into the device at the time.  To test on another device simply log in to the same Apple ID on the other device and open TestFlight- The app will be available

Comment: well what if i want to sent another invite to the same user

Comment: There is no need to send them another invite once they have accepted.  If they are using a different Apple ID on the second device and don't want to change it then you will need to send them a new invite to a different email address.

Comment: @Paulw11 Allright well im just gonna check this out and let you know whether this works. If you would be so kind to post this as an answer  so others having the same query may find this helpful. cheers mate